# How to convert each pair of { and } into ( and )?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am a learn-by-example person. I have no idea to change every `{` and `}` to `(` and `)` respectively. Could you let me know which concept in Mathematica is related to this problem so I can learn it much faster?

The objective is to convert the output of

```
Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {1, 2}}]
```

which is

> {{a, 1}, {a, 2}, {b, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 1}, {c, 2}}

to LaTeX-friendly output as follows. I have learnt `TeXForm` but it must be called at the last phase.

```
$\{(a, 1), (a, 2), (b, 1), (b, 2), (c, 1), (c, 2)\}$
```

Comment: `TeXForm` is an output format.  You can only achieve what you want as an output format, called at the last phase, like `TeXForm`.  You can defined your own output formats, with [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html), and the solutions to the linked question.

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Unless you have a large number of these it looks like a job for a text editor (preferably `grep`-friendly) or even a $\LaTeX$ macro that temporarily redefines `{}` (although it is also a nice hack to learn in MMA!).

Answer (score 2):

I see...

```
StringForm["(``,``)", ##] & @@@ {{-3, 
    0}, {0, -1}, {1, -2}, {2, -5}, {4, 7}, {5, 4}, {6, 3}, {9, 
    2}} // TeXForm
```